# Guid Object in Function Return in COM Interface

Tags: c#, .net, perl, com

I have a COM Interface which has function signature as mentioned below:

**Guid** `GetGuid2()`

It is implemented in a class:

```
    public Guid GetGuid2()
    {
      return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

Then this function needs to be used by Perl.

```
    my $dotNetLib = 'MyCOMDLL';
    my $server = Win32::OLE->new($dotNetLib) || die "Unable to launch server\n";
    my $guid = $server->GetGuid2();
```

But I am getting this error:

> Win32::OLE(0.1601) error 0x80020005: "Type mismatch" at Playground.pl

Is it possible for us to return GUID Object in COM Layer?

Comment: Are you sure you have correct sample pasted: differnet names `GetGuid` and `GetGuid2` used in C# and perl portions...

Comment: It was a typo error.. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you need to return a GUID from COM via .NET  you need to convert it to a Byte[] or a String and then rebuild it to a guid on the other side or perform string comparision, as a GUID isn't a COM Compatible type.

Comment: Hi Paul,  We need to get GUID object so that We can assign the GUID to another object's property. If converting to string is the only option we have got, then we will go in that route. But Exploring if there any we can expose GUID in COM Layer.

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying, because I needed to do the same thing. This is the approach I ended up having to take.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your comment